# Event Listeners to know when a page is Bookmarked/Downloaded

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to track when a page is bookmarked or downloaded in Firefox? I
mean is there any event that is triggered on bookmarking or
downloading a page? I am using Add-on SDK for developing Add-on.

If not, then kindly suggest me some workarounds.

Comment: No, not within the Add-on SDK. Btw, -1 for asking a question in the newsgroup and immediately posting it here as well - please be patient and wait for an answer in the newsgroup.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, i am extremely sorry to be this impatient but actually i am kinda working under a deadline and i didn't know that posting it here will target the same people as to that on Google Groups.

And about the question. If Add-on SDK doesn't provide any functionality for this,  is there any workaround ? 

Playing around with XPCOM..will it do? If yes, then please guide me to proper resources

Comment: Referencing the Google groups thread: http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack/browse_thread/thread/3a16d2ad8a49f3b2

Answer (score 4):

The browser window has [`<command>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/command) that get triggered when the user bookmarks or downloads a page. The former has ID `Browser:AddBookmarkAs`, the latter `Browser:SavePage`. The Add-on SDK itself doesn't give you access to them, so you need to use the [`chrome` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) to access XPCOM directly. Something like this:

```js
// Add listener to all existing browser windows
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var mediator = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                 .getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
var enumerator = mediator.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
  listenToWindow(enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow));

// Get notified when new browser windows open
var observers = require("observer-service");
observers.add("chrome-document-global-created", function(window)
{
  if (window instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow && window.location.href == "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul")
    listenToWindow(window);
});

function listenToWindow(window)
{
  window.document
        .getElementById("Browser:AddBookmarkAs")
        .addEventListener("command", onBookmark, false);
  window.document
        .getElementById("Browser:SavePage")
        .addEventListener("command", onSavePage, false);
}
```

This code isn't tested so there might be minor issues but the overall concept should be correct.

**Edit**: Actually, the same seems to be simpler if you use the internal `window-utils` package. Not sure whether the API provided by this package is stable however.

```js
var windows = require("window-utils");
for (window in windows.browserWindowIterator)
  listenToWindow(window);

var observers = require("observer-service");
observers.add("chrome-document-global-created", function(window)
{
  if (window instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow && windows.isBrowser(window))
    listenToWindow(window);
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't throw any exception. But still its not working. Basically `onBookmark` and `onSavePage` functions are not being called. So mostly Events are not triggered on bookmarking and downloading.

Answer (score 1):

It is all in the addon sdk documentation. Although I must admit I did not see it the first time around.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/event-targets.html

The following example is from the documentation.

Note that I had to add Cr to the require to make it work

as well as substitute Components.interfaces by Ci in the generateQI() call.

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu, Cr} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);    
var bookmarkService = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                          .getService(Ci.nsINavBookmarksService);

var bookmarkObserver = {
  onItemAdded: function(aItemId, aFolder, aIndex) {
    console.log("added ", bookmarkService.getBookmarkURI(aItemId).spec);
  },
  onItemVisited: function(aItemId, aVisitID, time) {
    console.log("visited ", bookmarkService.getBookmarkURI(aItemId).spec);
  },
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsINavBookmarkObserver])
};

exports.main = function() {
  bookmarkService.addObserver(bookmarkObserver, false);   
};

exports.onUnload = function() {
  bookmarkService.removeObserver(bookmarkObserver);
}
```